# Mac OS X VPN Encryption Defaults

Tags: vpn, mac

I need to connect one Mac (OS X 10.8.2) from our internal network to a site-to-site VPN and was asked to provide some information about our network and encryption settings. What are the OS X defaults for the following?

- Encryption Type (DES/3DES/AES)
- Hash (MD5/SHA1)
- Diffie-Hellman Group (1,2 or 5 )

According to this [Cisco VPN support doc](https://supportforums.cisco.com/docs/DOC-15887), Mac OS X 10.7 (and presumably 10.8) uses 3des or aes encryption, not des.

Where would I find the Hash and DH Group?

Comment: I also don't understand why these can't all be rolled into a .pcf file.

Comment: FYI, The DES key can be recovered in less than a day using "Cloud" GPUs. If anyone want your data, it'll cost them ~$200 USD of Amazon EC2 time. You probably don't change your encryption key very often either; most Cisco configurations I've seen never change their keys...

Comment: After upgrading to OSX 10.11.4 it is worth to add Diffie-Hellman 14 (2048bit). Source https://www.cameronbrister.com/mac-os-x-10-11-4-breaks-some-cisco-ipsec-vpn-connections/

Answer (score 5):

After extensive research, I've found consensus on which encryption settings OS X uses for VPNs. These may be useful for anyone setting up a VPN for native OS X or iOS clients.

- Encryption Type: **3DES** or **AES** (3DES is the default)
- Authentication Hash: **SHA-1**
- Diffie-Hellman Group: **DH Group 2 (1024 bit)**

Selected sources:

- *[Using a Linux L2TP/IPsec VPN server with Mac OS X and iPhone](http://www.jacco2.dds.nl/networking/openswan-macosx.html)
   (2010)*
  3DES, SHA-1, DH Group 2
- *[Set up IPSecuritas VPN for Mac OS X](http://www.hosting.com/support/juniper-netscreen-firewalls/set-up-ipsecuritas-vpn-for-mac-os-x) (undated)*
  3DES, SHA-1, DH Group 2
- *Use Mobile VPN with IPSec with a Mac OS X or iOS Device (undated, 2011?)*
  AES-256 or 3DES, SHA-1, DH Group 2
- *Application Notes for IPSec Policy supporting Apple iPhone VPN Connectivity (2010)*
  AES-128, SHA-1, DH Group 2
- *Setting up a Mac/iPhone VPN to a Cisco ASA Router (2009)*
  3DES, SHA-1, DH Group 2
- *SonicWALL and iPad, iPhone, iPod VPN solution Part 1 (undated)*
  3DES, SHA-1, DH Group 2
- *Diffie-Hellman (DH) Group 2 GroupVPN Limitation with MAC OS X Internet Connect and Windows Built-in L2TP Over IPSec Clients (2007)*
  DH Group 2

Comment: I hit the hyperlink limit, searching on the source titles should turn up the unlinked documents.